# Cannot send invites to facebook mobile app

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I bought a plugin(php) for my social networking site, and I configured it according to the instructions. I am also familiar with some coding but not expert.

So, the issue is I have configured the APP in facebook developer section and it works fine and sends out the invite see the below screenshot:

[image: Invite Friends Box]

but invites are being sent to user if user is using the website, See screenshot bellow.

[image: Notification Received on Site]

meaning invites notification don't appear on Facebook mobile application(Not even a push notification)

Maybe I need something to configure in the app?

If you want me to look for some code in the plugin I can do that, as I am not expert I cannot paste any relevant code in here. Sorry about that.

Thanks in advance.